# Can you use multiple types of sensors in the Autodesk Forge example program?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Been playing around with the autodesk forge example programs and haven't come across one which incorporates data from multiple different types of sensors, is this something which is doable, or do I need to have all of my sensors be the same type?

looking to add more later, but the 2 types I would like to incorporate into the example program for now are as follows:
type 1: measures temperature, humidity, and CO2 levels as doubles
type 2: measures room occupancy as a boolean
(as a bonus, any ideas on how to represent a boolean visually would be much appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the [Data Viz Extensions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/introduction/overview/) in Forge Viewer. The extension and the reference application have been built to work best with numerical (floating point) IoT data but you're free to represent any kind of data in any way you want. If you're simply interested to indicate that a room is either occupied or empty, the easiest approach in my opinion would be to just color the corresponding room object using the [setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive) method. Or, if you want to stay within the Data Viz Extension toolset, you could follow [this tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/create_heatmap_for_rooms/), and implement the `getSensorValue` function so that it returns a numerical value based on your boolean flag.